# Undefined value for initial state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still pretty new with ReactJS and now I ran into something which confuses me totally.

I've created a bunch of components which render a Bootstrap modal. Furthermore I fetch initial state parameters from the sever through the `componentDidMount` function. My component structure looks something like this:

```
<App>
  <Modal Lauch Button /> 

  <Modal>
   <Modal Header />
   <Modal Body />     <-- here's the problem
  </Modal>
</App>
```

and my initial state array is of the form (of course JSON encoded):

```
array:5 [▼
   ...
   ...
   "private" => true
   "files" => array:2 [▼
       1 => array:7 [▼
          "id" => 0
          "route" => "some route"
          ...
          ...
       ]
       2 => array:7 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "route" => "some other route"
          ...
          ...
       ]
   ]
]
```

and my (minified) React application like this:

```
<script type="text/babel">

    var L5fmModalBody = React.createClass({

        render: function() {

            return(
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Grid fluid={true}>
                        <Row>
                            {
                                this.props.files.map(function (file) {
                                    return <L5fmModalBodyFileContent id={file.id} route = {file.route} / >
                                })
                            }
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                </Modal.Body>
            );
        }

    });

    var L5fmModalBodyFileContent = React.createClass({

        render : function() {
            return(
                <Col xs={6} md={4} className="img-row">
                    <div className="thumbnail thumbnail-img">
                        <img key={this.props.id} src={this.props.route} />
                    </div>
                </Col>
            );
        }

    });

    var L5fmModal = React.createClass({

        getInitialState : function() {
            return {
                data : []
            };
        },

        componentDidMount: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'L5fm/setInitialState',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    this.setState({data: data});
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(this.state.data);
                }.bind(this),
                error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this)
            });
        },

        render: function() {

            return(

                <Modal {...this.props} bsSize="large" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg">
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <div className="header-button-group">
                            some buttons
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Header>

                    <L5fmModalBody files={this.state.data.files} />
                </Modal>
            );
        }

    });


    var App = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return { lgShow: false };
        },
        render: function() {
            let lgClose = () => this.setState({ lgShow: false });

            return (
                 <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={()=>this.setState({ lgShow: true })}>
                    Launch large demo modal
                 </Button>
                 <L5fmModal show={this.state.lgShow} onHide={lgClose} />
            );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("modal"));

</script>
```

Whenever I run the application I get following error:

> L5fmModalBody_renderTypeError: this.props.files.map is not a function. (In 'this.props.files.map', 'this.props.files.map' is undefined)

If I `console.log(this.state.data.files)` in my `<Modal>` component, it also shows that `this.state.data.files` is undefined? Obviously I have not understood what is going on. I've also tried to fetch data with `componentWillMount` but this did not help either. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE

I think I got a step further. The actual issue is not that `this.set,state` is `null` at the start, because after `componentDidMount` is called and the "new" states are set, the UI gets rendered again. Furthermore I found out that JSON apparently handles assoziative arrays as objects and I believe that I can't call `map` on an object.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `this.state.data` log?

Comment: If I put `console.log(this.state.data)` into the render function of `<L5fmModal>` I get `[] (0)` as log output. I guess that is just the predefined empty `data` array. But how can I fetch data from the server and THEN render the whole application?

Comment: @FlorianRagossnig: no need to do like that because first time it will render just UI and then call the API once API success function you have already set state again so it will again call your render function and now you have data so it will populate UI with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Dhaval Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1304880/dhaval-patel) I finally have the answer to this issue. The problem was not the `null` value of the initial state because when `componentDidMount` gets called the UI gets rendered again and receives the updated states from the server. The actual problem was that **JSON treats associative arrays as objects** and therefore I could not call a simple `map`.

I just changed

```
{
    this.props.files.map(function (file) {
        return <L5fmModalBodyFileContent id={file.id} route = {file.route} / >
    })
}
```

to

```
{
    Object.keys(object).map(
        function(d){
            return <L5fmModalBodyFileContent id={object[d].id} route={object[d].route} />
    })
}
```

where `object = this.props.files` and it works like a charm!

To avoid the error of the (at first) undefined object I've used

```
{this.state.data.length!=0 ? <L5fmModalBody files={this.state.data.files} />:null}
```

in the `<Modal />` component.

Answer (score 2):

yes of course it will throw error because you are passing this `<L5fmModalBody files={this.state.data.files} />` and your state it's declare in  `data : []` that means when first render happen data is just a blank array and your component render on your browser once that done then your L5fmModal's `componentDidMount` called and it will fetch the data from DB and again update state and render function called and data have a **file** field but what about very first load when your array is just an empty at that time **file** field is undefined so you have to implement below mentioned code in your `L5fmModalBody`

```
     {
(type of this.props.files != 'undefined')? this.props.files.map(function (file) {
                                        return <L5fmModalBodyFileContent id={file.id} route = {file.route} / >
                                    }):null                                
}
```

or you can also prevent from your `L5fmModal` it self using

```
{this.state.data.length>0 ? <L5fmModalBody files={this.state.data.files} />:null}
```

Comment: Hi Dhaval! thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this solution does not work. The Modal gets rendered but without body content.

Comment: @FlorianRagossnig:that means your data is always null check your API call

Comment: I thought so and I think I'm a step further now. I realised that my return "array" is actually not an array but an object and I believe I can't use `map` on an object. Do you have any tips for this issue?

Comment: @FlorianRagossnig: yes you can use Object.keys(data).map(function(d){return <L5fmModalBodyFileContent id={data[d].id} />});